# Android Studio error al compilar con Xiaomi

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con un Navigation Drawer imagen: https://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/android-navigation-drawer-activity.png  y quería hacer que a través de darle click a la imagen de arriba del navegador(dónde está la imagen de android) que se abriera el documento Fragment del perfil(imagen en donde estaría el perfil), para hacer esto simplemente he puesto en el onClick de este objeto la función:

```
public void Perfil(View view)
{
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

Al compilar con el Nexus 6 Android 8 del Emulador de ADV me funciona sin problemas, pero al compilarlo con mi móvil Xiaomi Mi5s al darle a donde la imagen de android en el Navigation Drawer se me apaga la aplicación, en el Debug me pone esto:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.julianrc1.petracecitm, PID: 19086
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type com.example.julianrc1.petracecitm.Usuario, but got android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4456)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5544)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.